# Generic methods in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have more of a .NET background, so I've been having some trouble coming up with a generic method I need in Java. Basically, I have a base class, call it `AbstractBase`, from which my domain objects inherit from (call them `ClassA` and `ClassB`). I want to write a method that returns a specific type of `AbstractBase` with a given ID. Here's how I might do it in C#:

```
public T getById<T>(long id) where T : AbstractBase
{
    if (T is ClassA)
        // find and return object of type ClassA
    else if (T is ClassB)
        // find and return object of type ClassB
    else
        return null;
}
```

I don't think I have my head fully wrapped around the way Java does generics. Is something like this possible to do with Java? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Oh, you poor C# soul.  Type erasure -- prepare to weep.

Comment: @KirkWoll: +1 I couldn't agree more. :'(

Comment: the whole point of generic code is that it is "generic" i.e. does not depend on type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public <T extends AbstractBase> T getById(long id, Class<T> typeKey) {
    if (ClassA.class.isAssignableFrom(typeKey)) {
        // ...
    } else if (ClassB.class.isAssignableFrom(typeKey)) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or if you want exact match on classes (rather than be of a potential subclass type):

```
public <T extends AbstractBase> T getById(long id, Class<T> typeKey) {
    if (typeKey == ClassA.class) {
        // ...
    } else if (typeKey == ClassB.class) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was what I was looking for. Thanks, Chris! Will accept as answer shortly...